# What is the meaning of electric potential = x Volt at any point in the circuit?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, electricity, potential

Does it mean: x Joule work is done to bring an unit positive charge from infinity to a point in that circuit?

OR

Does it mean: x Joule work is done to bring an unit positive charge from one point of the circuit to the same point traversing the whole circuit(EMF?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we talk about the potential at a point in a circuit this is always relative to some other point in the circuit. For a simple circuit with a single battery the reference point is usually the negative terminal of the battery. In that case the potential at a point is the energy required to move a unit positive charge from the negative terminal of the battery to that point.

Your second definition:

> Does it mean: x Joule work is done to bring an unit positive charge from one point of the circuit to the same point traversing the whole circuit(EMF?)

is not quite correct because the energy required to move a unit charge around the whole circuit is zero. That is, the unit charge gains energy as it moves through the battery then loses the energy again as it flows round the rest of the circuit. This is [Kirchhoff's voltage law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_voltage_law).